# state can not set in functional component

Tags: reactjs, state, react-functional-component

i send dataSource parameter to flowing functional component, dataSource has data but chartOptions state can not set.
thanks...

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Trend = ({ dataSource }) => {
  const [chartOptions, setChartOptions] = useState({
    series: {
      data: dataSource.map(x => {
        return ["TEST1", "TEST2"];
      })
    }
  });
  console.log(chartOptions);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>TEST</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Trend;
```

Comment: Did you tried using `useEffect`,

Comment: function are stateless thats you have to use Hooks for that to setState

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set it as this, as it sets state before the dataSource arrives.
Try using useEffect and set the state there like

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const data = dataSource.map(x => {
        return ["TEST1", "TEST2"];
      });

    setChartOptions(
    series: {
      data: data
            }
      );

  },[dataSource]);
```

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the value of your own state from a prop you should use useEffect and include this prop in the hook useEffect within the dependency array so that whenever it changes the value of the state is updated.

Yo can see it in the React documentation, [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

This could be an implementation:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = ({ dataSource }) => {
  const [chartOptions, setChartOptions] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    setChartOptions({
      series: {
        data: dataSource.map(x => {
          return ["I'm ", "test2"];
        })
      }
    });
  }, [dataSource]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        {chartOptions.series &&
          chartOptions.series.data.map(chartOption => <div>{chartOption}</div>)}
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[Here's an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-nmvtx)

PD: If you want a more extensive explanation about useEffect (it is quite complex) and where you will solve doubts about updating the state through props, etc I attach [an article by one of the developers of React](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) that I think is very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy initial state -
 If the initial state is the result of an expensive computation, you may provide a function instead, which will be executed only on the initial render:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
  const initialState = {
    series: {
      data: dataSource.map(x => {
        return ["TEST1", "TEST2"];
      })
    }
  }
  return initialState;
});
```